# Can't connect the razorpay payment gateway

Tags: javascript, html, razorpay

My html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
function payment(){
var options = {
    "key": "my id", // My id
    "amount": "50000",
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Acme Corp",
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_signature)
    },
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
        alert(response.error.code);
        alert(response.error.description);
        alert(response.error.source);
        alert(response.error.step);
        alert(response.error.reason);
        alert(response.error.metadata.order_id);
        alert(response.error.metadata.payment_id);
});
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <button id="rzp-button1" onclick="payment()">Pay</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whereas the payment gateway wasn't integrated to my page. I've seen many tutorials and videos related to this. I did the same did by them yet I couldn't achieve what they achieved :(

Kindly help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick="payment()"` from button since an onclick handler is already registered above. Wrapping the entire logic in payment() is not required. Just move the script below the form.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
 <form>
     <button id="rzp-button1">Pay</button>
 </form>
</body>

<script>    
 var options = {
 ...
 };

 var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
 rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
 ...
 });

 document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
     rzp1.open();
     e.preventDefault();
 }    
</script>

</html>
```